# Editing a json file with javascript

Tags: json, discord.js

So I have a command that sets the server prefix to the prefix that they said
this is the code that im using rn

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(',prefix')) {
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
if (args(0)) return message.channel.send('what do you want the prefix to be'); 
let prefixm = args.slice(1).join(' ')
if (!prefix[message.guild.id]) prefix[message.guild.id] = {
        prefix: `${prefixm}`
};
fs.writeFile("./db/prefix.json", JSON.stringify(prefix), (error) => {
    console.error();
})
message.channel.send(`server prefix set to: ${prefixm}`);
}
})
```

so when the user sends ,prefix ! it edits the last prefix that the server had
and I looked all over the internet and nobody has done it on javascript yet so that why I need your help

please and thank you

Comment: Your question has a few issues. Its title doesn't reflect what you actually want to do. It sounds like you want to change a particular setting on your Discord server based on a user sending a message to your bot. If so, your question title would be based on that. Also, can you fix your code formatting? Formatting like `if (!prefix[message.guild.id]) prefix[message.guild.id]` is strange. You should put the statements you want to execute below the condition on a new line. And you should use curly braces around the statements, even if there's only one. Also, you should indent your code.

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is about solving particular problems given a clear explanation of a problem, the code you used to get the problem, and the goal you have. If your question is more open ended, like "I want to solve problem x. I don't have code that tries to do anything about that yet, because I don't know where to start. What suggestions do people have?" then you should consider posting it on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, with explanation:
**prefix.json**

```js
{
"Placeholder" : {
"prefix": ","
}
}
```

^^^Placeholder for a guild^^^
**index.js** - or whatever file you use the prefix in

```js
//function to require uncached
function requireUncached(module) {
delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
return require(module);
}

//message event callback with prefix
let prefixes = requireUncached('./prefix.json');
let prefix = prefixes['G'+message.guild.id].prefix;
//prefix is now the chosen prefix

//message event callback for new prefix:
//or guildCreate event could use default prefix
let newPre = message.content.split(/ +/)[1];
let prefixes = requireUncached('./prefixes.json');
prefixes['G'+message.guild.id].prefix = newPre
fs.writeFile('./prefixes.json', JSON.stringify(prefixes), err => {
if(err) throw err;
console.log(`Prefix saved as ${newPre}`)
})
//you can modify this for guildCreate event
//so that you won’t get error cannot 
//set property prefix of undefined
```

You can also use fs.readFile instead of requireUncached but idrk how to use that.